# Could Breakthrough Starshot spacecraft detect hypothetical Planet Nine?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics

Since we just want to prove if Planet Nine exists in our solar system and know the approximate position of the planet if it exists, we can avoid most of the technical challenges for StarChip (camera not required, speed much slower than the planned speed, etc). So StarChip would become much cheaper, and we are able to launch thousands of the spacecraft, covering a large area of the sky. If a massive object exists within the area, it will affect nearby passing spacecraft and lead to trajectory anomaly, which maybe detectable and be used for calculating the possible position of the object, and then we can do some follow-up observations using telescopes.

So could this technique be used for detecting Planet Nine or any other unknown massive object in the solar system?

Comment: Interesting thought.  Probably it would make sense to use fewer probes and target the general regions that seem most likely to contain a Planet 9.  It would still take a pretty long time for the probes to get that far, but multiple relatively slow-moving probes could provide enough data to get a fairly decent gravity map of the outer Solar System, and thereby reveal any major masses that might be lurking out there.